# Best way to get data from a service to a reactive form in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm searching for the best way to fill a form with data from a service in Angular 5. I wanted to have as little component code as possible, thats my variable-data is stored within the services and not the component.

My services actually load the content via a second service.

**Example Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

private user: User;

private url: string = 'v1/user';

constructor(
    private restService: RestService

) {
    this.restService.get(this.url).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.user = res;
        }
    );

}

public getUser(): User {
    return this.user;
}
```

**Example Component:**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

private form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private userService: UserService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Initalize the empty form
    this.form = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl()
        })
    );

    // Fill the form with values from the service
    this.form.patchValue(this.userService.getUser());
}
```

When I actually wait for a time (like 10 seconds with setTimeout) and then execute the patchValue() everything works, but obviously that is not optimal.

Is there a way to know when the code in the service is loaded, aside from going *to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut* and using an Observable?

I'm thankful to any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can actually make your service act as an resolver and achieve your goal this way.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService implements Resolve<any> {

    private user: User;

    private url: string = 'v1/user';

    constructor(
        private restService: RestService
    ) {}

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.restService.get(this.url).map(
            user => {
                this.user = user;    
            },
            error => {}
        ).first();
    }

}
```

And afterwards in your router you add the service to your route, as you would do it for a normal resolver.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: {
            user: UserService
        }
    }
]

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [UserService] 
})
```

This way the service data is refreshed everytime you navigate in your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe inside your component instead, or you could create a subject that emits the values once done.

Subscribing inside component

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

private user: User;

private url: string = 'v1/user';

constructor(private restService: RestService) {}



public getUser() {
    return this.restService.get(this.url);
}
```

In component.ts

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

private form: FormGroup;
    userSub: Subscription;
    user: string;
constructor(
    private userService: UserService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   userSub = this.userService.getUser()
     .subscribe( (res) => { 
        this.user = res;
         // Initalize the empty form
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            'email': new FormControl(this.user, [])
             })
        );
     });

}
```

---

Subscribing to a subject in service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
userRetrieved: new Subject<User>();
private user: User;

private url: string = 'v1/user';

constructor(
    private restService: RestService

) {
    this.restService.get(this.url).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            this.user = res;
            this.userRetrieved.next(this.user);
        }
    );

}

public getUser(): User {
    return this.user;
}
```

Then in your component, subscribe to it

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
userSub: Subscription;
private form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private userService: UserService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Initalize the empty form
    this.form = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl()
        })
    );
    this.userSub = this.userService.userChanged
       .subscribe((res: User ) => { 
        //Code to update and Fill the form with values from the service
        // this.form.patchValue(res);
       });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but actually thats what I wanted to avoid. The reason for this is, that I have the same data in many, many components (user is kind of an unfitting example for that). And then I would have the same code in all of them... seems not ideal to me...

Comment: In my opinion, the services only have to return Observables; and in my opinion too, it is clearer if a function is done to build formControl (pass empty data or an object). In general, the form does not have to have the same fields as the data.

Comment: Could I somehow use an _Resolve Guard_ to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if making async calls in a service constructor is a good practice. Never had to do it.